# What does “Pourvu que ça tienne !” mean in this context?

Tags: sens, interjections

What does “Pourvu que ça tienne !” mean in this context?

[image: From Tintin au Pays de Soviets]

Answer (score 4):

I think it could possibly have [two meanings](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/pourvu).

The most probable meaning (espérons que) is exactly what pat27 said, which could also be translated as "Let's hope it (the car) holds up/stays in one piece" or in order to capture more fully the sense of "[pourvu que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pourvu%20que)" and Milou's fear of the consequences if the car in fact fails to hold up, perhaps the following:

> For the sake of our own survival, let's hope that it holds up.

The other meaning (à condition que), although probably a little far-fetched, but perhaps slightly indicated by the ellipses following Tintin's statement is that Milou/Snowy is actually finishing Tintin's statement with

> AS LONG AS (instead of "Let's hope") it (the car) holds up/stays in
>   one piece,

which would give the meaning of "He's going to bomb us again if/only if (provided that) the car holds up" (slightly optimistic, I suppose) or the more pessimistic  "He'll continue dropping bombs as long as/(so long as) the car holds up."

Comment: thanks a lot man, good analysis. In english that was translated to: “Let’s hope it holds!”

Comment: The second explanation doesn't hold because of the exclamation point at the end of Milou's "Pourvu que ça tienne!"

Comment: Agreed that the exclamation point means that it certainly works for the "espérons que" option, and as I said the "à condition que" option is probably far-fetched, but couldn't a two-clause sentence beginning with "He's going to bomb us again.." be viewed as at least a little exclamatory, meriting it's own exclamation point, which it would get by tacking on "if the car holds up!" to it? @BernardMassé

Comment: Unrelated note - *Tintin au pays des soviets* is truly underrated. As an art piece, but sadly also as a propaganda stereotypic example.

Answer (score 3):

it means "I hope it will remain operational". He hopes his repair/assembly won't break .

Comment: thanks!! :) I just downloaded an english version that translated that to: “Let’s hope that holds!”